# Can an if statement conditional in Java be on multiple lines

Tags: java

I have a long if statements in my program and I was wondering if there was a way to simply continue the conditional onto the next line so that it doesn't stretch off forever.

Here's my statement:

```
if (Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(1)) && Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(3)) && Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(4)) && Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(6)) && Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(7)) && Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(8)) && Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(9)))
```

I'm just trying to ensure that a string containing a date is of the format I specified.

Comment: Yes, just press Enter.

Comment: You could try it you know...

Comment: However, I would suggest using a loop for this.

Comment: In Eclipse use **CTR** **SHIFT** **F**. It will format your code.

Comment: use regex to do that.

Comment: I would suggest a regular expression.

Comment: The way you've written it, it will throw an exception if the date that's entered is less than  10 characters.

Comment: If it's a date, then parse the date (for example with a SimpleDateFormat) and check if an exception is thrown. That will be easier to read and maintain, and probably less error prone.

Comment: You can put a newline after every token in the statement if you want to.  `if \n ( \n Character \n . \n isDigit \n ( \n enroleDate \n ....`

Comment: The compiler will ignore whitespaces. You can write your entire program in a single line if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

But why not just try it?

```
if  (
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(0)) && 
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(1)) && 
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(3)) && 
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(4)) &&
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(6)) && 
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(7)) && 
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(8)) && 
        Character.isDigit(enrollDate.charAt(9))
    )
```

Anyway, you could try to improve this `if`

Comment: Just to add, any statement of code such as method calls, and what not (besides strings) can all be on multiple lines.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Thanks, I did try it but I was just wanting to verify that it actually is okay to do this and that there isn't anything special you need to account for when doing this.

Comment: @user3397166 Nope, is the same thing you can do it with this if and with others too.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, you can definitely break out your `if` into multiple lines.

However...

The format that you're working with smells like this:

```
\d\d[-/]\d\d[-/]\d\d\d\d
```

That is, you have any two numbers preceding a dash or slash, followed by two other numbers preceding a dash or slash, followed by four numbers.

I'm 99% sure that this is a date of some kind.

If *that's* the case, then there's an easier way to do this:  [`DateFormat#parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

`parse` may throw a `ParseException`, so you could either hard-wire it into the method...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
    System.out.println(fmt.parse("03-30-2014"));
}
```

...or write a try-catch block around it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
    try {
        System.out.println(fmt.parse("03-30-2014"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The latter may give you a chance to recover from a disastrous parsing attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marco, yes you can use multiple lines, but you need to improve this condition. Is it enrollDate is a string? You could use int tryparse for the hole string instead of verifing each char.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally if you have suggestions that would be helpful, but aren't an answer, comments are the best place for them. I realize that initially you may not be able to leave comments, but adding an answer isn't always the best approach. If you do feel the comment is important, try to also address the main issue the OP is facing. In your case, it might be helpful to write a small piece of code demonstrating what you are suggesting.

Comment: Thanks, you're the first one being nice. Some of this guys are really rude... It's difficult to start helping others in here...

Comment: It can take some time to get involved, absolutely, and you'll have a few bumps along the way. Keep trying, and be sure to learn from each "failure" as much as from your successes. At the end of the day I think most everyone here is really trying to help other people with their problems, so it should balance out overall.